# Has there been a security patch in Micropython for the KRACK bug in the WPA2 handshake?

Tags: python-3.x, micropython

I assume that connecting a ESP8226 chip without a patch could make the entire network vulnerable? Extremely unlikely someone is going to go through the mess to get in that way yes, but it would be good to know anyway. Thanks!

Comment: This would be much better asked on the Micropython forum, I think.

Comment: ...And it has been asked, [here](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=3966&p=22740&hilit=krack#p22740) - but not answered at time of writing this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the official SDK has been patched:

http://espressif.com/en/media_overview/news/espressif-releases-patches-wifi-vulnerabilities-cert-vu228519

Comment: So Espressif has patched their SDK, but I assume the OP would like to know if/when the patch has been incorporated into the Micropython firmware - or can it be applied independently?